# Hurewicz model structure and cofibrantly generated model categories

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Is it an open problem if $\mathbf{TOP}$ with Hurewicz (Strøm) model structure is cofibrantly generated?

Answer (score 7):

I have a vague memory of being told that someone has proven that the Strom model structure is not cofibrantly generated. I would ask Boris Chorny or Carles Casacuberta.

That said, a map $f \colon X \to Y$ is a Hurewicz fibration if and only if it lifts against the inclusion $Nf \to Nf \times I$, where $Nf$ denotes its mapping cocylinder. From this observation, there is a generalized (algebraic) version of the small object argument that allows one to formally construct the model-theoretic functorial factorization. This is explained in a paper "On the construction of functorial factorizations for model categories" that I wrote with Tobias Barthel.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  I think I have located [your joint paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.5427) at arXiv.org.

Comment: Toby remembered a reference, Emily: Homotopy Theory of Posets by George Raptis, Remark 4.7. He also pointed out that you give this reference in Example 12.7.6 of your book. :)

Comment: That explains the vague memory ;)

Comment: Does George Raptis was the first one to show that?